# Set proxy on Windows 10 with Python and winreg

Tags: python, proxy, winreg

I'm trying to use the module `winreg` to change the values of `ProxyEnable`, `ProxyOverride` and `ProxyServer` stored in `SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings`.

I use the follow code

```
INTERNET_SETTINGS = winreg.OpenKey(winreg.HKEY_CURRENT_USER,
                                   r'SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings',
                                   0, winreg.KEY_SET_VALUE)

def __set_winreg_key__(name, value):
    _, reg_type = winreg.QueryValueEx(INTERNET_SETTINGS, name)
    winreg.SetValueEx(INTERNET_SETTINGS, name, 0, reg_type, value)

ip = "x.x.x.x"
port = 8080

__set_winreg_key__('ProxyEnable', 1)
__set_winreg_key__('ProxyOverride', '*.local;<local>')
__set_winreg_key__('ProxyServer', f"{ip}:{port}")
```

But i get a **PermissionError: [WinError5] Access Denied**.

I use PyCharm to execute the script and even if i run it as *admin* the error persists.

My setup is:

- Python 3.8 (64-bit)
- PyCharm Community Edition 2020.1
- Microsoft Windows 10 Home

Answer (score 0):

The access is denied because the key was not "open for querying".

Add `winreg.KEY_QUERY_VALUE` flag:

```
INTERNET_SETTINGS = winreg.OpenKey(winreg.HKEY_CURRENT_USER,
                                   r'SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings',
                                   0, winreg.KEY_SET_VALUE | winreg.KEY_QUERY_VALUE)
```

Comment: Thanks, this seems did the trick, i noticed that in my registry editor in the folder `Internet Settings` there aren't `ProxyOverride` and `ProxyServer` keys, how it is possible?

Comment: I don't think those keys are there by default. You'll need to create them first before setting their values.